# Minimum size of room in flat rental UK in an non-HMO?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, landlord, rent

I have rented a flat in London and I was wondering whether the landlord is renting it illegally due to the size of the rooms. I am aware that there is a minimum room size requirement for the HMO (house in multiple occupation) rentals. However, is there a similar line for an non-HMO?

In addition, I am aware that new homes have a minimum room requirements as per the article: https://urbanistarchitecture.co.uk/minimum-space-standards/

but my flat is not new and it does not look renovated either.

Comment: A bit of browsing [here](https://www.lettingagenttoday.co.uk/breaking-news/2018/12/government-clarifies-rental-property-minimum-room-size-guidance) and [here](https://landlordknowledge.co.uk/landlord-guidance-room-size-regulations/) indicates that the (bed)room sizes apply to all rented accomodation, but the sources mention HMO as being a concern, perhaps because they typically have smaller room sizes. For example: *All landlords must ensure that they keep to the room size specifications laid down. This had caused concern to landlords, particularly with Houses in Multiple Occupation HMOs).*

Comment: I believe you're confusing building codes or standards with possible laws regarding habitability.  The properties you're asking about were likely either legal when they were built, as standards change over time, or were "grandfathered" in when the codes were added.

Comment: @WeatherVane I can only find the information about HMO occupations and I know that a landlord was forced to make a room bigger to be legal. In my case, I rent a two bed flat with a living room and they can say that I can sleep in the bigger room. Should it be classified as a 2bed flat if at least 1 bedroom is small? I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Comment: IMO the small bedroom can't be described as a bedroom if is below the legal minimum size. The links I posted don't seem to apply just to HMOs, see the quote above: "***All** landlords..."* Please read what [Shelter](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/repairs/check_if_your_home_is_overcrowded_by_law) has to say on the matter - it doesn't even mention HMOs.

Comment: @WeatherVane I will ask the shelter. Thanks

Comment: Welome, the organisation is called "Shelter".